# Python object matching using string

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching

Why i am not able to find the match?

```
>>> ti = "abcd"
>>> tq = "abcdef"
>>> check_abcd = re.compile('^abcd')
>>> if check_abcd.search(ti) is check_abcd.search(tq):
...     print "Matching"
... else:
...     print "not matching"
...
not matching
```

Eventhough both variables ti and tq are matching and having same reference

```
>>> print check_abcd.search(ti)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7ffbb05559f0>
>>> print check_abcd.search(tq)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7ffbb05559f0>
```

Why it is not matching?

Comment: try `if check_abcd.search(ti).group() == check_abcd.search(tq).group():`

Comment: Store the two objects in separate variables and then try. Then their ID will be different (Coz the older object will be overwritten)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
`is` is identity testing, == is equality testing. 
 is will return True if two variables point to the same object, == if the objects referred to by the variables are equal.
```

You probably want to match `values` and not `objects`.So you can use

```
ti = "abcd"
tq = "abcdef"
check_abcd = re.compile('^abcd')

if check_abcd.search(ti).group(0) == check_abcd.search(tq).group(0):
    print "Matching"
else:
    print "not matching"
```

Comment: Hey vks! The OP seems to ask as to why `is` operator is not working even though the  object reference point to the same ID. Your answer is perfect! But keep it on hold till the OP clarifies :)

Comment: Naw! They'll be overwrittten. That's why even I'm on standby :) [Check this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959371/python-object-matching-using-string#comment46171769_28959371)

Comment: Yes vks and Bhargav, == is working fine when used with group as attribute. I thought that eventhough objects refer to same id, why it was not matching even if i use == or is.

Comment: @user2982007 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963860/curious-case-of-is-operator#28964095

Comment: @BhargavRao http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963860/curious-case-of-is-operator#28964095

Comment: @vks I knew that Martijn was the only person who could explain it correctly !!! Both the ques and answer are great +1 .... :)

Comment: General Saab!  We had this torment everyone in our placement interview :'(