# "is" operator not working as intended

Tags: python

Just have a look at this code:

```
import re

ti = "abcd"
tq = "abcdef"
check_abcd = re.compile('^abcd')
print id(check_abcd.search(ti))
print id(check_abcd.search(tq))
print check_abcd.search(ti)
print check_abcd.search(tq)
if check_abcd.search(ti) is check_abcd.search(tq):
    print "Matching"
else:
    print "not matching"
```

Output:

```
41696976
41696976
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000027C3ED0>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000027C3ED0>
not matching
```

Definition of `is`:

```
`is` is identity testing, == is equality testing. 
 is will return True if two variables point to the same object
```

1)Now why is the `is` not returning `True` when id as well as object reference is same.

2)When `is` is replaced by `==` it is still returning `false`.Is that the expected behaviour when comparing objects using `==`.

Comment: Due to **Garbage collection**.

Comment: Python **reuses** id values when the variable is cleared.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary `Garbage collection`??????any links or more info?

Comment: @MartijnPieters when does the variable get cleared?

Comment: @vks: when the reference count drops to 0.

Comment: vks: This may help: Look at this tutor:  http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import+re%0D%0A%0D%0Ati+%3D+%22abcd%22%0D%0Atq+%3D+%22abcdef%22%0D%0Acheck_abcd+%3D+re.compile('%5Eabcd')%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aa,+b+%3D+check_abcd.search(ti),+check_abcd.search(tq)%0D%0Aprint+a%0D%0Aprint+b&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0

Comment: Related: [Why does `id({}) == id({})` and `id([]) == id([])` in CPython?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877230/why-does-id-id-and-id-id-in-cpython), [Identity of class methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792202/identity-of-class-methods) etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never assigned the return values, so after printing the `id()` value of the return value of `check_abcd.search()` calls, Python *discards* the return value object as there is nothing referencing it anymore. CPython object lifetimes are directly governed by the number of references to them; as soon as that reference count drops to 0 the object is removed from memory.

Discarded memory locations can be re-used, so you'll like to see the same values crop up in `id()` calls. See the [`id()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id):

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. **Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.**

At no point in your code did you actually have *one* object, you have two separate objects with non-overlapping lifetimes.

Assign return values if you want to make sure `id()` values are not reused:

```
>>> import re
>>> ti = "abcd"
>>> tq = "abcdef"
>>> check_abcd = re.compile('^abcd')
>>> ti_search = check_abcd.search(ti)
>>> tq_search = check_abcd.search(tq)
>>> id(ti_search), id(tq_search)
(4378421952, 4378422056)
>>> ti_search, tq_search
(<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x104f96ac0>, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x104f96b28>)
>>> ti_search is tq_search
False
```

By assigning the return values of `check_abcd.search()` (the regular expression `MatchObject`s) an additional reference is created and Python cannot reuse the memory location.

Comment: If lets say `id's` get reused.....why did `is` operator not returning `matched` ?

Comment: @vks: because it is *not the same object*. `is` doesn't test for memory location. It tests if something is actually the exact same object.

Comment: In each case *except* the conditional statement, the value is created and released *within* the statement.  But the conditional cannot release the first value until it's evaluated *both* values which is why, within that single expression, Python creates two distinct result values from .search().  See my annotated code in a separate answer.

Comment: Thanx a lot.....that was helpful!!!!!!...Can you throw some light or share some doc about what reference count is

Comment: @vks: This may help: [Reference Counts](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/intro.html#reference-counts).

Comment: @vks Had told you about this [earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959371/python-object-matching-using-string/28959676?noredirect=1#comment46171769_28959371) :) However Martijn's answer has cleared everything! @ Martijn Can you please edit the title to have it define the problem more? (So that in future it will help everyone :) )

Comment: FWIW, it's likely not defined whether the two return values can have the same ID since it's an immutable type and `search` is free to cache its results - I'd imagine it's highly unlikely to break but it still strikes me as the wrong place to be using `is`.

Comment: @Veedrac: using `is` should be reserved for very specific usecases; this is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

WHen you do:
`print id(check_abcd.search(ti))`  in a line and don't store the return value of `search` anywhere, its reference count goes to zero and it is destroyed. The call in the line bellow that creates another object, which happens to be in the same memory address (which is used by CPython as an object ID) - but it is not the same object.

When you use the `is` operator, the previous object still has to exist in order for the comparison to occur, and its address will be different.

Just put the results of the calls to `check_abcd.search` in a variable before printing their ID (and use different variables) and you will be able to see what is actually going on.

Moreover: continuing in these lines can be instructive if you want to learn about the behavior of "is" and object IDs  - but if you want to compare strings, and return values, just use the `==` operator, never `is`: subsequent function calls, even if returning the same value are not supposed to return the same object  - the `is` comparison is only recommended when comparing with "None" (which is implemented as a singleton)

Comment: Thanx a lot....is would be helpful if you can post some link about `reference count` and wht the scope of it is

Comment: Don't worry about reference counting - it is done automatically bby Python for any object you instantiate. All you need to know is that if there are no references to an object in any variables/objects, it is destroyed, and its memory is made available for creation of other objects.

Comment: 'the `is` comparison is only recommended when comparing with "None"' → Or any predefined enumerables, really (such as using `object()` as a sentinel).

Answer (score 2):

Martjin has given you the correct answer, but for further clarification here is an annotated version of what's happening in your code:

```
# this line creates returns a value from .search(), 
# prints the id, then DISCARDS the value as you have not 
# created a reference using a variable.
print id(check_abcd.search(ti)) 

# this line creates a new, distinct returned value from .search()
# COINCIDENTALLY reusing the memory address and id of the last one.
print id(check_abcd.search(tq))

# Same, a NEW value having (by coincidence) the same id
print check_abcd.search(ti)

# Same again
print check_abcd.search(tq)

# Here, Python is creating two distinct return values.  
# The first object cannot be released and the id reused
# because both values must be held until the conditional statement has 
# been completely evaluated.  Therefore, while the FIRST value will
# probably reuse the same id, the second one will have a different id.
if check_abcd.search(ti) is check_abcd.search(tq):
    print "Matching"
else:
    print "not matching"
```

Comment: Great answer with lot of comments which I adore. But are you sure that it is *by coincidence* ?

Comment: I thought of adding a note about that -- obviously it's replicable and therefore not truly coincidence; Python is consistently reusing the last id.  But I decided to leave the word coincidence since that's how it *should* be treated.  The real coincidence is that the code creates and discards two objects in order that *appear* to be related to each other.