# Can someone explain the behaviour of empty dicts in python generator expressions?

Tags: python, dictionary, generator-expression

Some friends and I were discussing things related to memory management in Python when we stumbled upon the behaviour below:

```
In [46]: l = ({} for _ in range(6))

In [47]: [ id(i) for i in l]
Out[47]:
[4371243648, # A
 4371245048, # B
 4371243648, # A
 4371245048, # B
 4371243648, # etc.
 4371245048]
```

What is surprising here is that we don't seem to have well defined behaviours: the dict is neither a new one each time nor the same reference each time.

On top of that, we got this weird behaviour (not code was run in the interpreter between these two snippets).

```
In [48]: m = ({} for _ in range(6))

In [49]: [ id(i) for i in m]
Out[49]:
[4371154376, # C
 4371245048, # B (same B as above!)
 4371154376, # C
 4371245048, # B
 4371154376,
 4371245048]
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Using list comprehensions (`l = [{} for _ in range(6)]`) shows different addresses for each dict.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28963860/2003420) might give you a good idea of what's going on

Comment: Did you read the [`id()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id)? You missed something crucial there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not surprised about `id()` reusing the same number. I was surprised about the face that it reused the same number *while I kept a reference to it* (which was my fallacy).

Comment: @sitaktif: right, you are not keeping any references to the `{}` objects you generate; the generator produces them, but doesn't reference them afterward.

Comment: @sitaktif: I think you went wrong here: *the dict is neither a new one each time nor the same reference each time*. It *is* a new dict each time; the left-hand expression in a generator expression is evaluated anew each iteration.

Comment: @MartijnPieters absolutely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionaries are being destroyed as soon as they are no longer referenced by the generator.  You are comparing the ID's of dead objects, and ID's can be reused.

Comment: This is exactly what I missed - the fact that with a generator, I lose the reference to the item. Thanks!